# A new expression requires () or... in LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors

This is driving me nuts.

I have the following code that, when a button is clicked, a gridview will be populated with data based on the number a client enters into a text box (tbxHowMany).

```
 protected void btnDisplayTopReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (radPa.Checked)       
      {

            CompleteWeightsDataContext db = new CompleteWeightsDataContext
            int max = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(tbxHowMany.Text, out max))
            {
                var queryPa = db.tblOnlineReportingCOMPLETEWeights
                    .Where (x => x.MaterialLevel == "Primary" && x.MaterialText == "Paper")
                    .OrderByDescending (x => x.ProductPercentage).Take(max);

                GridView1.DataSourceID = "queryPa";
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
       else if (radGl.Checked)
         {
              CompleteWeightsDataContext db = new CompleteWeightsDataContext
            int max = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(tbxHowMany.Text, out max))
            {
                var queryGl = db.tblOnlineReportingCOMPLETEWeights
                    .Where (x => x.MaterialLevel == "Primary" && x.MaterialText == "Glass")
                    .OrderByDescending (x => x.ProductPercentage).Take(max);

                GridView1.DataSourceID = "queryGl";
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
         }
       }
```

Unfortunately I keep on getting "a new expression requires (),[], etc" on the first int.

Can someone explain to me the error and/or what I have done wrong and how I can work around this?

Apologies for the, most likely dim, question.

Comment: sorry - the "int max = 0;" int causes the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error is actually on the line before (it shows up as on that line, because the line before isn't properly terminated, so `int max...` is where the compiler first realizes something's gone wrong.

The error is here:

```
CompleteWeightsDataContext db = new CompleteWeightsDataContext
```

It should be:

```
CompleteWeightsDataContext db = new CompleteWeightsDataContext();
```

Comment: I can't believe I missed that! I think I need some lunch!

Thanks for the fresh pair of eyes David.